# Refused to execute script from 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/

Tags: google-ads, google-tag-manager, tag-manager

I just added tags to track the conversion of our Google Ads and according to Google Tag Assistant, all is fine (the tag is blue; "To validate please enter the feed ID").

But in the console, I get this error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   `https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1010235.../someStuffThatSpecifiesOurWebsite...`
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME
>   type checking is enabled.

I get that the browser is expecting JS and receives HTML instead, but this is a script sent by Google, so it feels a little out of my control.

Other people are talking about this issue on Advertiser Community, but the one solution presented there is to turn off blocking of third party cookies, which of course, didn't work for me.

Any tip much appreciated!